# Is there a way to use NUnit TestCase attribute with optional arguments

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, optional-parameters

I'm trying to run some test cases but I need to make one of the arguments optional.

I've tried the following but NUnit ignores the tests and prints the following "ignored: Wrong number of arguments provided"

```
[TestCase(Result = "optional")]
[TestCase("set", Result = "set")]
public string MyTest(string optional = "optional")
{
    return optional;          
}
```

Is it possible to run test cases with optional arguments?

Comment: This is not possible with the current version of NUnit. But I believe this would be a senseful enhancement for the upcoming v3 which is currently in development. You could open a feature request for this on [their Github project](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-framework/issues).

Answer (score 6):

Just make 2 test in this case, optional paramerters are not supported in nunit:

```
[TestCase("set", Result = "set")]
public string MyTest(string optional)
{
    return optional;          
}

[TestCase(Result = "optional")]
public string MyTest()
{
    return MyTest("optional");          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to test two different things here, so I would **lean toward using two separate tests** for this, as [peer already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22196109/336648).

If for some reason you really need or want it in one test, you could use either `null` or a constant as a parameter, and add code to handle it in your test. Be careful not to make the logic in the test too complicated though (ideally, there should not be any logic in a test..).

```
const string NO_VALUE = "Just a const to identify a missing param";

[TestCase(null, Result = "optional")] // Either this... 
[TestCase(NO_VALUE, Result = "optional")] // or something like this
[TestCase("set", Result = "set")]
public void MyTest(string optional)
{
    // if(optional == null)  // if you use null
    if(optional == NO_VALUE) // if you prever the constant
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else{
        // Do something else
    }        
}
```

Comment: Oops, meant to remove that. Fixed now. My point was that you can pass something else that indicates that nothing should have been passed (as when using optional parameters). That way, you can sort of fake the optional parameter behaviour. Sort of a hack, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON as TestCase:

```
[Test]
[TestCase(@"{
        'Param1': 123,
        'Param3': true,
        'Param5': 'Abc'
    }")]
public void MyTest(string json)
{
    var testParams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParamsModel>(json);
}

private class ParamsModel
{
    public int Param1 { get; set; }
    public string? OptionalParam2 { get; set; } = null;
    public string Param3 { get; set; }
    public string? OptionalParam4 { get; set; } = null;
    public string Param5 { get; set; }
}
```